# Split json file into multiple csv files depending on date?

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, alpha-vantage

I am trying to split up a json file from alpha-vantages api into separate files depending on the date. I'm also trying to reformat the file to have blank values in the gaps where dates are missing. The following code is what I have come up with but it gives me the TypeError: 'list' object is not callable". I'm fairly new to python and pandas so I'm sure there is a better way to go about this.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil import parser
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame
import json


symbol = "MSFT"

symbol_list = symbol.split(",")


def num_el(list):
    count = 0
    for element in list:
        count += 1
    return count


def csv_make(sy, dar, dat):
    csv_file = open(f"{sy}_1min_{dar}.csv", "w", newline="")
    csv_file.write(dat)
    csv_file.close()


i = 0
x = -1
n = num_el(symbol_list)
while i < n:
    namesym = symbol_list[x]
    ticker = namesym
    api_key = 'APIKEYHERE'
    url = f'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol={ticker}&outputsize=full&interval=1min&apikey={api_key}'
    data = requests.get(url)
    dsf = data.json()
    daf = pd.DataFrame(dsf['Time Series (1min)'])
    dxf: DataFrame = daf.T
    dxf.index.name = 'time'
    dxf.reset_index(inplace=True)
    dxf['time'] = pd.to_datetime(dxf['time'])
    dxf['minute'] = dxf['time'].dt.time
    dxf['day'] = dxf['time'].dt.day
    dxf['date'] = dxf['time'].dt.date
    agg = dxf.groupby([dxf['day']])
    length1 = dxf.groupby([dxf['day']]).size()
    length = pd.DataFrame(length1)
    length.index.name = 'day'
    length.reset_index(inplace=True)
    length_sum = length[0].sum()

    v = 0
    d = length_sum
    b = len(length)
    x2 = length_sum
    while v < b:
        a = length[0][v]
        x2 -= length[0][v]
        xd = agg.get_group(length['day'][v])
        date = xd['date'][x2]

        max_dt = parser.parse(str(max(xd['minute'])))
        min_dt = parser.parse(str(min(xd['minute'])))

        dt_range = []
        while min_dt <= max_dt:
            dt_range.append(min_dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
            min_dt += timedelta(seconds=60)

        complete_df = pd.DataFrame({'minute': dt_range})

        xy = complete_df.astype('str')
        yx = xd.astype('str')

        dasf = xy.merge(yx, how='left', on='minute')
        dasf['ev'] = np.where(dasf['1. open'].notnull(), 'False', 'True')

        time = []
        open = []
        high = []
        low = []
        close = []
        volume = []
        empty_value = []

        for ib in range(len(dasf)):
            time.append(dasf['minute'][ib])
            open.append(dasf['1. open'][ib])
            high.append(dasf['2. high'][ib])
            low.append(dasf['3. low'][ib])
            close.append(dasf['4. close'][ib])
            volume.append(dasf['5. volume'][ib])
            empty_value.append(dasf['ev'][ib])

        time_df = pd.DataFrame(time).rename(columns={0: 'Time'})
        open_df = pd.DataFrame(open).rename(columns={0: 'Open'})
        high_df = pd.DataFrame(high).rename(columns={0: 'High'})
        low_df = pd.DataFrame(low).rename(columns={0: 'Low'})
        close_df = pd.DataFrame(close).rename(columns={0: 'Close'})
        volume_df = pd.DataFrame(volume).rename(columns={0: 'Volume'})
        empty_value_df = pd.DataFrame(empty_value).rename(columns={0: 'Empty Value'})

        frames = [time_df, open_df, high_df, low_df, close_df, volume_df, empty_value_df]
        df = pd.concat(frames, axis=1, join='inner')
        df = df.set_index('Time')
        ad = df.to_csv()
        csv_make(namesym, date, ad)
        v += 1

    i += 1
```

Comment: Can you give the line number / point out where the error happens ?

Comment: Can you explain the value of *num_el()* please? It seems strange to see something like that when the rest of the code is, whilst not exactly "advanced", is clearly written by someone who has some idea about what they're doing

Comment: @log0 When I run the program, it gives me the following error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\data_scraper_alphavantage\alphavantage_intraday.py", line 109, in <module>
    csv_make(namesym, date, ad)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\data_scraper_alphavantage\alphavantage_intraday.py", line 24, in csv_make
    csv_file = open(f"{sy}_1min_{dar}.csv", "w", newline="")
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: Ok I think I know. Do not use `list` as a variable name. You are messing all codes using lists afterward. same thing for ` open` further down.

Comment: @BrutusForcus The num_el() part of the code is something I got from someone else. As I said, I'm new to python so I did my best to put together what I thought would work. In terms of what it is meant to do, it is meant to return the number of symbols I have listed in the symbol = "MSFT" part of the code. It is there so I can write multiple symbols e.g. symbol = "MSFT,AAPL", then the while loop would put that symbol into the "url".

Comment: @log0 Yep, that was the issue. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @FOURZA07 you can replace `num_el(symbol_list)` with `len(symbol_list)`